# reverse duplicate direction

Tags: discussion

I just hit on this question in the review queue: [Is there way to see `man` document only for specified option of a command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180639/is-there-way-to-see-man-document-only-for-specified-option-of-a-command)

It is going to be closed as a duplicate of this: [How to filter any part of description or option from manpage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159214/how-to-filter-any-part-of-description-or-option-from-manpage)

I thought that this is not a good idea, was going to ask about it but found an answer (in my opinion): https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2841/32191

This answer omits one important point, though: What to do if the others have already started to vote this in the wrong direction? First comes to my mind to flag it and have the mod reverse the closing. Maybe it is possible to vote for closing as duplicate in the other direction but I would probably lose that as the other reviewing is a few votes ahead. I might add a comment on both questions but probably that just delays losing.

Of course, there could be a technical solution: The close votiong dialog could be extended by a second voting for the closing direction. On the other hand this may happen so seldom that individual handling by the mods is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think flagging is the best choice.  This does not happen very often so we shouldn't have any problem dealing with this.  Just flag one of the two posts and let us know what's wrong.

In this particular case,  the questions were close enough that I just merged them.  Thanks for bringing it up.